# Tricky Question re Customer Purchase Probabilities

Tags: probability, distributions

I would like to calculate some parameters relating to customer purchasing in a retail situation.

I have some basic information which I can use:

Customer visit frequency in the form of probability distribution (I can generate Excel poisson tables using average visit frequency and these work well) for number of customer visits in a given period (1 month), e.g.:

0 Customers: 14%
1 Customer: 27%
2 Customers: 27%
3 Customers: 18%
4 Customers: 9%
5 Customers: 4%
6 Customers: 1%
.... etc

Customer purchase quantity per visit (based on observation), e.g.:

1 unit: probability = 60%
2 units: probability = 25%
3 units: probability = 10%
4 units: probability = 4%
5 units: probability = 1%
(max 5 units)

The data points above are provided by way of example but will differ from case to case.

I would like to calculate the probability of a total of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11…. etc, units being purchased in the given time period. I think I can do this if the max number of customers is very small (2 or less!) but am struggling to see how to achieve this in a more general case where the numbers of potential customers n are larger! Once I know how to do the calculation, I would like to implement this in Excel.

To make this clearer: Case for 1 customer is simple, being 5 options (using my data: probability of 1 customer is 27% who is likely to purchase 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 units with probabilities 60%, 25%, 10%, 4% ,1%). I can then calculate probability of selling 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 units by multiplying.

The case for n = 2 customers has 25 options (I think) (customer 1 with 5 options x customer 2 with 5 options). For this case I may sell 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, or 10 units and I can multiply and sum the probabilities manually. This result would then be added to the result for 1 customer.

However, with the case for n = 3 customers there would be 125 options and the adding and multiplying already starts to become hairy. In practice, my customer visit table may extend to many more than 3 customers so the problem quickly becomes difficult to manage without having some kind of general formula.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is the sum of independent random variables.  This can be calculated either by convolution or by using moment generating functions.

[discrete convolution formula](https://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st311-rich/convol.pdf)
so in excel you should be able to do it in a spreadsheet or in vba: basically you split the problem up- calculate sum of 2 variables-> then you repeat with pdf of sum of 2 variables and next variable

or you calculate the mgf of #objects purchased with 1 customer( see calculation for discrete probability mass in wikipedia article) 
then you use the 'sum of independent RVs is product of mgfs' to get the mgf for n customers. finally you get the distribution of n customers purchases by inverting the mgf (which will again be a discrete distribution).
[wiki:mgf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function)

Updated.  So what I am suggesting is to use the discrete convolution formula for $Z=X+Y$. You have worked out how to calculate it for two customers - and all I am suggesting is just do that repeatedly.  Take two customers, then $X$ is customer 1 and $Y$ is customer 2, and use the formula to calculate the pdf Z for 2 customers. Now to calculate the pdf for 3 customers you use the pdf for 2 customers which you just calculated ( call that now X) and the pdf of 1 customer purchase (Y) in the same formula. so in terms of VBA you might write a function with the following declaration :conv(pdf_x, pdf_y)  which given 2 2-D arrays (1 column for  quantity and 1 for probability) would produce a new 2-d array pdf_z.   then you would call it repeatedly to get the pdfs for 3,4,5,6,... etc

$P(Z=z)=\sum_{x=0}^z f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)$

Comment: Seanv507, apologies for the very delayed thank you to your answer. Actually, when I read your comments and looked at the links I was rather  taken aback as the knowledge required to understand clearly exceeded my own! However, I am still trying to find an answer to this question. If you see this comment, perhaps you could point me in the direction of a worked example which might make things easier to understand and allow me to dig in deeper?